# Variable (dynamic) OPTION lists in HTML SELECT using IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-select

I'm trying to implement a dynamic OPTION list in JavaScript.  Depending on other selections in the web form, some of the OPTIONS in a specific SELECT are not valid.  Things I've tried that don't work in IE are:

- populate all options, then set the disabled property for those that are invalid
- populate all options and use option groups, then disable invalid option groups
- I even tried using a style of text-decoration:line-through

At this point I'm resigned to repopulating the SELECT with only valid OPTIONs, but it seems like there ought to be a better way that actually works in IE.  I require compatibility with IE6 and up.  How have you dealt with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE doesn't support the disabled attribute on options](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-293-cant-disable-options-in-ie.html), and worse yet, [IE doesn't support events on options](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html), and the [styling abilities are very limited in IE](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-291-no-styling-options-in-ie.html).

Until IE joins the rest of the browser world in terms of common support for basic elements and basic functionality, you are SOL.

Answer (score 0):

Is it such a problem to repopulate the select with just the valid options? I've used this method many times and haven't encountered any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, just won't work in IE, was face palming repeatedly on this one a few weeks ago; gave up, just put in only valid options instead.

Did find this: http://elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com/2007/05/activating-option-disabled-in-ie.html,
and this: http://www.danieltome.com/blog/2007/08/16/disable-options-in-a-multiple-select-javascript-for-ie/
 have not tried either yet, but may do the job for you.

Don't know if they are fixing it in IE 8.

In this case, select really is broken...

Comment: not sure about the final ver of IE8, but IE8 Beta2 still fails and there is no indication that they intend to fix for the Final.